# IList<T> in multi map/reduce result?

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I'm struggling with RavenDB's multi map/reduce concept and recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610243/does-multi-map-reduce-work-in-ravendb) regarding how to properly write a multi map/reduce index.

I got the simple index in that question working but when I tried to make it a bit more complicated, I cannot make it work. What I want to do is to have the result of the index to contain a list of string, i.e:

```
class RootDocument {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  public string Bar { get; set; }
  public IList<string> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDocument {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string RootId { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

class RootsByIdIndex: AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<RootsByIdIndex.Result> {
  public class Result {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
  }

  public RootsByIdIndex() {
    AddMap<ChildDocument>(
      children => from child in children
        select new {
          Id = child.RootId,
          Foo = (string)null,
          Bar = (string)null,
          Items = default(IList<string>),
          Value = child.Value
      });
      AddMap<RootDocument>(
        roots => from root in roots
          select new {
           Id = root.Id,
           Foo = root.Foo,
           Bar = root.Bar,
           Items = root.Items,
           Value = 0
        });
      Reduce = 
        results => from result in results
          group result by result.Id into g
            select new {
              Id = g.Key,
              Foo = g.Select(x => x.Foo).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
              Bar = g.Select(x => x.Bar).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
              Items = g.Select(x => x.Items).Where(
                x => x != default(IList<string>).FirstOrDefault(),
                Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
              };
    }
}
```

Basically I tried to set the Items property to default(IList) when mapping the ChildDocuments and to value of the RootDocument's Items property. This doesn't work, however. It gives the error message

> Error on request Could not understand query:
>
> -- line 2 col 285: invalid Expr
>
> -- line 2 col 324: Can't parse double .0.0

when uploading the index. How do I handle lists in multi map/reduce indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use List in your indexes, instead, use arrays.

```
AddMap<ChildDocument>(
  children => from child in children
    select new {
      Id = child.RootId,
      Foo = (string)null,
      Bar = (string)null,
      Items = new string[0],
      Value = child.Value
  });
  AddMap<RootDocument>(
    roots => from root in roots
      select new {
       Id = root.Id,
       Foo = root.Foo,
       Bar = root.Bar,
       Items = root.Items,
       Value = 0
    });

Reduce = 
    results => from result in results
      group result by result.Id into g
        select new {
          Id = g.Key,
          Foo = g.Select(x => x.Foo).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
          Bar = g.Select(x => x.Bar).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
          Items = g.SelectMany(x=>x.Items),
          Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
          };
```

Answer (score 2):

David, you need to understand that RavenDB stores its indexes with Lucene.NET. That means, you cannot have any complex .net type inside your index.

In your example, I suggest you use a simple `string` instead of `IList<string>`. You can then join your string-items:

```
AddMap<ChildDocument>(
  children => from child in children
    select new {
      Id = child.RootId,
      Foo = (string)null,
      Bar = (string)null,
      Items = (string)null,
      Value = child.Value
  });
  AddMap<RootDocument>(
    roots => from root in roots
      select new {
       Id = root.Id,
       Foo = root.Foo,
       Bar = root.Bar,
       Items = string.Join(";", root.Items),
       Value = 0
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I just assumed I could index anything I could store (and storing an IList<string> works fine).